# Regular Expression to match certain formula

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to regular expression. I was wondering how I can use regular expression to replace

```
001-34/323
To 
001/34-323
```

I have something like this

```
 return Regex.Replace(input, 
               "\\b(?<p1>\\d{1,2})/(?<p2>\\d{1,2})/(?<p6>\\d{2,4})\\b",
               "${p1}-${p2}-${p3}", RegexOptions.None.
```

I have something like this but it doesn't work it does the opposite of what I want

input has all integers. Please let me know the regular expression that will change the input to the output
Thanks

Comment: 1) Can you show the regular expression you've written for this. If you've not written anything, be advised that SO is not a code-writing service. 2) The accompanying code to effect the replace would be different between javascript and C# - which one are you working with?

Comment: Just added code that I tried but didnt work

Answer (score 2):

Your current regular expression expects a number like this:

```
P1/P2/P3
```

Where:

- P1 is a 1-2 digit number
- P2 is a 1-2 digit number
- P3 is a 2-4 digit number

Why isn't it working? Your input string is `001-34/323` (`P1-P2/P3`) and P1 is a 3 digit number. Additionally, your last capture group is called `<p6>`, not `<p3>`.

The correct string should be:

```
\b(?<p1>\d{1,3})-(?<p2>\d{1,2})/(?<p3>\d{2,4})\b
```

Or in escaped form:

```
"\\b(?<p1>\\d{1,3})-(?<p2>\\d{1,2})/(?<p3>\\d{2,4})\\b",
```

Your template for the output is also wrong (`P1-P2-P3`, not `P1/P2-P3`).

Final code example:

```
var input = "001-34/323";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, 
                   "\\b(?<p1>\\d{1,3})-(?<p2>\\d{1,2})/(?<p3>\\d{2,4})\\b",
                   "${p1}/${p2}-${p3}",
                   RegexOptions.None);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fina8U)

Comment: Also, [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZzLkuw/1) is an awesome resource for debugging your regex

Answer (score 0):

Why make it hard by trying to match the pattern of the data?

If you are just replacing a dash with a slash, use the match evaluator to return the opposite upon finding the dash or slash.

```
var text = "001-34/323";

Regex.Replace(text, "[-/]", me => { return me.Value == "-" ? "/" : "-";   })
```

**Result**

```
001/34-323
```